# How does the worker thread "steal" from another worker thread?

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I am trying to understand the stealing part of the fork-join.
A fork join pool has worker threads with its own Deque.
A worker thread steals from another worker if its own deque is  empty.

1. How can a thread access the state of some other thread?

   Will it not create synchronization problems when the owner thread and the stealer thread try to access the same item in the dequeue?

Answer (score 0):

The deque is a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque. The owning thread adds to the bottom of the deque. A stealing thread polls the top of the deque:

> poll() Retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this
>   deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), or returns
>   null if this deque is empty.

Therefore, there is no conflict.